# How to work with data in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

To read data is easy enough:

1. ViewModel gets data from the database
2. ViewModel adds the data to ObservableCollection
3. View binds the List/DataGrid/etc to the ObservableCollection

As follows:

```cs
private readonly ObservableCollection<User> _users
        = new ObservableCollection<User>();

public IEnumerable<User> Users
{
    get { return _users; }
}

public ICommand ListUsersCommand
{
        get
        {
            return new DoSomething(ListUsers);
        }
}
private void ListUsers()
{
    using (OrtundDbContext db = new OrtundDbContext())
    {
        var Users = db.Users.Where(x => x.Deleted == false);
        foreach (var u in Users)
        {
            if (!_users.Contains(u))
            _users.Add(u);
        }
    }
}
```

So this allows binding to `Users` in xaml so it seems logical to assume that more or less the reverse should be possible. That the updated values of the controls on the Window can be sent back and used in the ViewModel to update the data source there.

That's not what's happening unfortunately...

Currently I have the following:

```xml
<StackPanel DataContext={Binding ViewModels:UserViewModel}">
    <Label>Name:</Label>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <Button Name="btnAdd" Command="{Binding AddUserCommand}" Content="Add User" />
</StackPanel>
```

```cs
// Base model implements INotifyPropertyChanged
public class UserViewModel : BaseModel
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Name");
        }
    }

    public ICommand AddUserCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new DoSomething(AddUser);
        }
    }

    public void AddUser()
    {
        var User = new User
        {
            User.Name = Name // assign values based on properties.
        };

        using (OrtundDbContext db = new OrtundDbContext())
        {
            db.Users.Add(User);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that when I get to AddUser, it would seem the values of the properties for the ViewModel (`UserViewModel.Name`, for example) are all empty with no values from the form.

Am I doing this wrong? What's the proper way to update the data source from the UI?

Comment: Where is `UserViewModel.Name` defined?

Comment: On the ViewModel. I replaced the comment that was there with the property definition

Comment: Is Name not firing OnPropertyChanged?

Comment: It doesn't look like it though it should be

Comment: What's the DataContext of the TextBox that is bound to the Name property? Is the command getting fired, i.e. do you get to the AddUser() method when you click the button?

Comment: I've updated the question to include that

Comment: Your DataContext binding looks strange. Won't even compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you set the `DataContext` of the `TextBox` or any of its parent element to the actual instance of the `UserViewModel` that you invoke the command of:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.DataContext>
        <local:UserViewModel />
    </StackPanel.DataContext>
    <Label>Name:</Label>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <Button Name="btnAdd" Command="{Binding AddUserCommand}" Content="Add User" />
</StackPanel>
```

If you use the above sample markup and set a breakpoint in the `AddUser()` method, you should notice that the `Name` property has the value that you see in the `TextBox`.